# Speeding up a closest point on a hyperbolic paraboloid algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numpy, 3d

I wrote a python script which finds the UV coords of the closest point on surface from a query point (p). The surface is defined by four linear edges made from four known points (p0,p1,p2,p3) listed counter clockwise.

(Please ignore the little red ball)

[image]

The problem with my approach is that it is very slow (~10 seconds to do 5000 queries with a low precision threshold.

I'm looking for a better approach to achieve what i want, or suggestions to make my code more efficient. My only constraint is that it must be written in python.

```
import numpy as np

# Define constants
LARGE_VALUE=99999999.0
SMALL_VALUE=0.00000001
SUBSAMPLES=10.0

def closestPointOnLineSegment(a,b,c):
    ''' Given two points (a,b) defining a line segment and a query point (c)
        return the closest point on that segment, the distance between
        query and closest points, and a u value derived from the results
    '''

    # Check if c is same as a or b
    ac=c-a
    AC=np.linalg.norm(ac)
    if AC==0.:
        return c,0.,0.

    bc=c-b
    BC=np.linalg.norm(bc)
    if BC==0.:
        return c,0.,1.


    # See if segment length is 0
    ab=b-a
    AB=np.linalg.norm(ab)
    if AB == 0.:
        return a,0.,0.

    # Normalize segment and do edge tests
    ab=ab/AB
    test=np.dot(ac,ab)
    if test < 0.:
        return a,AC,0.
    elif test > AB:
        return b,BC,1.

    # Return closest xyz on segment, distance, and u value
    p=(test*ab)+a
    return p,np.linalg.norm(c-p),(test/AB)




def surfaceWalk(e0,e1,p,v0=0.,v1=1.):
    ''' Walk on the surface along 2 edges, for each sample segment
        look for closest point, recurse until the both sampled edges
        are smaller than SMALL_VALUE
    '''

    edge0=(e1[0]-e0[0])
    edge1=(e1[1]-e0[1])
    len0=np.linalg.norm(edge0*(v1-v0))
    len1=np.linalg.norm(edge1*(v1-v0))

    vMin=v0
    vMax=v1
    closest_d=0.
    closest_u=0.
    closest_v=0.
    ii=0.
    dist=LARGE_VALUE

    for i in range(int(SUBSAMPLES)+1):
        v=v0+((v1-v0)*(i/SUBSAMPLES))
        a=(edge0*v)+e0[0]
        b=(edge1*v)+e0[1]

        closest_p,closest_d,closest_u=closestPointOnLineSegment(a,b,p)

        if closest_d < dist:
            dist=closest_d
            closest_v=v
            ii=i

    # If both edge lengths <= SMALL_VALUE, we're within our precision treshold so return results
    if len0 <= SMALL_VALUE and len1 <= SMALL_VALUE:
        return closest_p,closest_d,closest_u,closest_v

    # Threshold hasn't been met, set v0 anf v1 limits to either side of closest_v and keep recursing
    vMin=v0+((v1-v0)*(np.clip((ii-1),0.,SUBSAMPLES)/SUBSAMPLES))
    vMax=v0+((v1-v0)*(np.clip((ii+1),0.,SUBSAMPLES)/SUBSAMPLES))
    return surfaceWalk(e0,e1,p,vMin,vMax)




def closestPointToPlane(p0,p1,p2,p3,p,debug=True):
    ''' Given four points defining a quad surface (p0,p1,p2,3) and
        a query point p. Find the closest edge and begin walking
        across one end to the next until we find the closest point 
    '''

    # Find the closest edge, we'll use that edge to start our walk
    c,d,u,v=surfaceWalk([p0,p1],[p3,p2],p)
    if debug:
        print 'Closest Point:     %s'%c
        print 'Distance to Point: %s'%d
        print 'U Coord:           %s'%u
        print 'V Coord:           %s'%v

    return c,d,u,v



p0 = np.array([1.15, 0.62, -1.01])
p1 = np.array([1.74, 0.86, -0.88])
p2 = np.array([1.79, 0.40, -1.46])
p3 = np.array([0.91, 0.79, -1.84])
p =  np.array([1.17, 0.94, -1.52])
closestPointToPlane(p0,p1,p2,p3,p)


Closest Point:     [ 1.11588876  0.70474519 -1.52660706]
Distance to Point: 0.241488104197
U Coord:           0.164463481066
V Coord:           0.681959858995
```

Comment: How exactly is your surface defined? Your definition gives the edges of the surface, but not the inner parts. It looks like you simply connect opposite edges with lines that connect the points that divide the opposite edges with the same ratio. Is that even well-defined? I bet it is, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do some profiling (see [line profiler](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/)) to see what your bottlenecks are. It's easier to speed up a few lines than a whole algorithm :)

Comment: I wondered the same.. I do not understand the algorithm. Anyway here are two suggestions (might be wrong): in this line `for i in range(int(SUBSAMPLES)+1):`, isn't it possible to replace this loop by binary search? It is quite likely that this function is firstly decreasing and after at some point starts increasing. Another thing is that this is purely mathematical procedure : I would rewrite it to C++ (use Cython for instance, it is quite easy)

Comment: Have you tried some kind of spatial partitioning? Your pic is a perfect example of it. Try sampling each vertex of each quad, and find the vertex with the smallest distance to your query point. Then you know the closest point lies in one of the 4 quads touching that point.
Edit: You could also try using multiprocessing and subdividing the problem out to multiple processes.

Comment: @gregb212 i lack the technical language to describe this surface, and the picture i posted is misleading in the sense that the grid you see isn't made of vertices and triangles. I mocked this up using a 3D application called Maya. The surface you see in the image is a linear NURBS surface. The best way i can describe it is if you imagine p0->p1 as line sliding on tracks definde by p0->p3 and p1->p2 all the way to the other end defined by p3->p2. The surface is essentially this sliding line duplicated infinitely.

Comment: @gregb212 I like the threading idea though! I'll give that a whirl.

Comment: Cool. Note that python threads do not work how you would expect them to. If you want C-like threads, you want to look at python multiprocessing instead. Google 'Global Interpreter Lock' to find more information on why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your surface is, as it seems, a hyperbolic paraboloid, you can parametrize a point `s` on it as:

```
s = p0 + u * (p1 - p0) + v * (p3 - p0) + u * v * (p2 - p3 - p1 + p0)
```

Doing things this way, the line `p0p3` has equation `u = 0`, `p1p2` is `u = 1`, `p0p1` is `v = 0` and `p2p3` is `v = 1`. I haven't been able to figure out a way of coming up with an analytical expression for the closest point to a point `p`, but `scipy.optimize` can do the job numerically for you:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

p0 = np.array([1.15, 0.62, -1.01])
p1 = np.array([1.74, 0.86, -0.88])
p2 = np.array([1.79, 0.40, -1.46])
p3 = np.array([0.91, 0.79, -1.84])
p =  np.array([1.17, 0.94, -1.52])

def fun(x, p0, p1, p2, p3, p):
    u, v = x
    s = u*(p1-p0) + v*(p3-p0) + u*v*(p2-p3-p1+p0) + p0
    return np.linalg.norm(p - s)

>>> minimize(fun, (0.5, 0.5), (p0, p1, p2, p3, p))
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 9
    nfev: 36
     fun: 0.24148810420527048
       x: array([ 0.16446403,  0.68196253])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    hess: array([[ 0.38032445,  0.15919791],
       [ 0.15919791,  0.44908365]])
     jac: array([ -1.27032399e-06,   6.74091280e-06])
```

The return of `minimize` is an object, you can access the values through its attributes:

```
>>> res = minimize(fun, (0.5, 0.5), (p0, p1, p2, p3, p))
>>> res.x # u and v coordinates of the nearest point
array([ 0.16446403,  0.68196253])
>>> res.fun # minimum distance
0.24148810420527048
```

---

Some pointers on how to go about finding a solution without scipy... The vector joining the point `s` parametrized as above with a generic point `p` is `p-s`. TO find out the closest point you can go two different ways that give the same result:

1. Compute the length of that vector, `(p-s)**2`, take its derivatives w.r.t. `u` and `v` and equate them to zero.
2. Compute two vectors tangent to the hypar at `s`, which can be found as `ds/du` and `ds/dv`, and impose that their inner product with `p-s` be zero.

If you work these out, you'll end up with two equations that would require a lot of manipulation to arrive at something like a third or fourth degree equation for either `u` or `v`, so there is no exact analytical solution, although you could solve that numerically with numpy only. An easier option is to work out those equations until you get these two equations, where `a = p1-p0`, `b = p3-p0`, `c = p2-p3-p1+p0`, `s_ = s-p0`, `p_ = p-p0`:

```
u = (p_ - v*b)*(a + v*c) / (a + v*c)**2
v = (p_ - u*a)*(b + u*c) / (b + u*c)**2
```

You can't come up with an analytical solution for this easily, but you can hope that if you use those two relations to iterate a trial solution, it will converge. For your test case it does work:

```
def solve_uv(x0, p0, p1, p2, p3, p, tol=1e-6, niter=100):
    a = p1 - p0
    b = p3 - p0
    c = p2 - p3 - p1 + p0
    p_ = p - p0
    u, v = x0
    error = None
    while niter and (error is None or error > tol):
        niter -= 1
        u_ = np.dot(p_ - v*b, a + v*c) / np.dot(a + v*c, a + v*c)
        v_ = np.dot(p_ - u*a, b + u*c) / np.dot(b + u*c, b + u*c)
        error = np.linalg.norm([u - u_, v - v_])
        u, v = u_, v_
    return np.array([u, v]), np.linalg.norm(u*a + v*b +u*v*c + p0 - p)

>>> solve_uv([0.5, 0.5], p0, p1, p2, p3, p)
(array([ 0.16446338,  0.68195998]), 0.2414881041967159)
```

I don't think this is guaranteed to converge, but for this particular case it seems to work pretty fine, and only needs 15 iterations to get to the requested tolerance.

Comment: Thanks!!! I'll see if i can get a VC10 64 bit version of scipy compiled so i can interface with it and i'll give your solution a whirl. Looks promising!

Comment: any way to do this purely in numpy?

Comment: My attempt To solve it analytically: The closest point will be the `point of contact` between a sphere centered at `p(xp, yp, zp)` and the hyperbolic paraboloid (`HP : z = xy`(1))- as you keep increasing the radius(`r`) of the sphere, at some point it will touch `HP`. A point on the sphere is given by (px+rcosθsinφ, py+rsinθsinφ, pz+rcosφ). From (1) pz+rcosφ = (px+rcosθsinφ)*(py+rsinθsinφ). You need to solve for r, φ and θ. I'm stuck at this point though :(.

Comment: @ArunR I don't think that would work... A hypar only has the equation you posted for some very particular coordinate axis, and finding those out is not an easy task. A fully analytical solution would probably require solving a third or fourth order equation.

Comment: @Fnord See my latest edit for a way of computing this without scipy.

Comment: @Jaime this is even better because i can make it even faster by lowering the tolerance to what i would consider an acceptable result (0.01~0.001) and even at high degree of precision it looks like this is even faster than the scipy solution. So thank you!

Comment: If no better solution comes up, i think @Jaime wins! :)

Comment: @Jaime, before i start a different thread, with the same input would it be difficult to approximate the surface area?

Comment: It's a doubly ruled surface, so probably it is relatively simple to compute it exactly. But my differential geometry is a little rusty to give an answer right away. So do go ahead an ask a new question. It is the right thing to do as well: people googling for "surface area of a hypar" won't get to the answer if it is buried in a comment thread.

Comment: @Jaime i did some test runs today and noticed that your solution doesn't limit the uv results to the surface's boundaries. So you end up with uv's beyond 1. or below 0.... what makes more sense in your opinion to solve this: a) get the result from solve_uv, if u or v is out of bounds ignore the result and project p to the appropriate edge. or b) clamp `u, v = u_, v_` in the iteration loop, or c) is there s better way?

Comment: It depends on your application, but from a purely geometrical perspective, if the closest point comes out of the range `[0, 1]` for `u` or `v`, I think the closest point would then be on one of the edges. If you calculate the distance to each of the edges, it could again happen that the closest point is outside the segment defined by your points. Then the closest point would be one of the vertices. If you mess with the values of `u` and `v` in the function, the result will not converge, so I wouldn't go that route.

Comment: @Jaime, after implementing your code, everything worked great but there are some edge cases, ex: p0=np.array([-0.156,1.142,0.114])
p1=np.array([-0.136,1.092,0.131])
p2=np.array([-0.101,1.092,0.150])
p3=np.array([-0.112,1.145,0.150])
p=np.array([-0.218,1.029,0.209]) will return UV coords way out there [2.6519415683050718, 6.5945574803442772] when in fact the result should be much closer. Do you have any recommendations to try to catch these edge cases?

Comment: The fact that both the scipy solver and the function I came up with converge to the same value leads me to believe that the point they find really is the closest. Notice that the distance it calculates is about `0.009`, while the distances from `p` to any of the `pi` are around `0.1` - `0.2`. So it's not an artifact of the solution method, but of your clipping the surface to its boundaries. Your closest point within those boundaries will have to lay on the boundary, so you will have to calculate the distance to the frontier segments and vertices and keep the smallest.

Comment: @Jaime is there a way to constraint the `uv` range between `0-1` so the closest point remains within the 4 edges? Right now to achieve this i take the result from your algorithm, check if `0<uv<1` and then do a projection to the closest edge to get a constrained result.