# Surface Area of a Hypar (hyperbolic paraboloid)

Tags: python, math, numpy, 3d

I've already posted this question about this topic:
[Speeding up a closest point on a hyperbolic paraboloid algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858448/speeding-up-a-closest-point-one-a-surface-algorithm)

Given four points (p0,p1,p2,p3) to define a [doubly ruled hyperbolic paraboloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_ruled_surface), what is the best (fastest) way to compute its surface area using python's numpy module?

[image]

Comment: Tried anything so far?

Comment: this surface seems to be described using finite elements, so you should calculate the area for each one and sum them up...

Comment: @SaulloCastro sorry if the image is misleading. The grid here is visible only to help visualize the surface. The surface type i'm dealing with is a doubly ruled hyperbolic paraboloid [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_ruled_surface)

Comment: @Fnord Do you have the surface equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more maths than programming, so you may want to check with the folks at [`math.stackexchange`](https://math.stackexchange.com/). But, from the answer to your previous question, the surface can be parametrized as:

```
s = p0 + u * (p1 - p0) + v * (p3 - p0) + u * v * (p2 - p3 - p1 + p0) =
    p0 + u * a + v * b + u * v * c
```

with the area limited by your four points being `0 <= u <= 1` and `0 <= v <= 1`.

You can get two vectors tangent to the surface by differentiation:

```
t1 = ds/du = a + v * c
t2 = ds/dv = b + u * c
```

And you can get a vector, perpendicular to the other two, with a norm equal to the area of the parallelogram described by them, taking their cross product:

```
A = t1 x t2 = a x b + u * a x c + v * c x b
```

It is tempting to simply go ahead and integrate A, but it is its norm you want to integrate, not the vector itself. I have tried feeding that to Mathematica, to see if it would come up with some nice, closed form solution, but it's been going for several minutes now without arriving anywhere. So you may as well do things numerically:

```
def integrate_hypar(p0, p1, p2, p3, n=100):
    a = p1 - p0
    b = p3 - p0
    c = p2 - p3 - p1 + p0
    delta = 1 / n
    u = np.linspace(0,1, num=n, endpoint=False) + delta / 2
    axb = np.cross(a, b)
    axc = np.cross(a, c)
    cxb = np.cross(c, b)
    diff_areas = (axb + u[:, None, None] * axc +
                  u[:, None] * cxb) * delta * delta
    diff_areas *= diff_areas
    diff_areas = np.sum(diff_areas, axis=-1)
    diff_areas = np.sqrt(diff_areas)
    return np.sum(diff_areas)
```

With the data points from your other question, I get:

```
p0 = np.array([1.15, 0.62, -1.01])
p1 = np.array([1.74, 0.86, -0.88])
p2 = np.array([1.79, 0.40, -1.46])
p3 = np.array([0.91, 0.79, -1.84])

>>> integrate_hypar(p0, p1, p2, p3)
0.54825122958719719
```

Comment: i got 0.0 returned from your code, and then made this quick correction and it works!  `delta = 1. / n` instead of `delta = 1 / n` Thanks again! You're machine!

Comment: This is such a good answer - I'd hate to see the question condemned to math-exchange.