# How to use scipy.optimize to minimize multiple scalar-valued functions simultaneously

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858448/speeding-up-a-closest-point-on-a-hyperbolic-paraboloid-algorithm) I asked for a way to compute the closest projected point to a [hyperbolic paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid) using python.

Thanks to the answer, I was able to use the code below to calculate the closest point to multiple paraboloids.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# This function calculate the closest projection on a hyperbolic paraboloid
# As Answered by @Jaime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858448/speeding-up-a-closest-point-on-a-hyperbolic-paraboloid-algorithm
def fun_single(x, p0, p1, p2, p3, p):
    u, v = x
    s = u*(p1-p0) + v*(p3-p0) + u*v*(p2-p3-p1+p0) + p0
    return np.linalg.norm(p-s)


# Example use case:
# Generate some random data for 3 random hyperbolic paraboloids
# A real life use case will count in the tens of thousands.
import numpy as np
COUNT = 3
p0 = np.random.random_sample((COUNT,3))
p1 = np.random.random_sample((COUNT,3))
p2 = np.random.random_sample((COUNT,3))
p3 = np.random.random_sample((COUNT,3))
p = np.random.random_sample(3)

uv = []
for i in xrange(COUNT):
    uv.append(minimize(fun_single, (0.5, 0.5), (p0[i], p1[i], p2[i], p3[i], p)).x)
uv = np.array(uv)

# UV projections for my random data
#[[ 0.34109572  4.39237344]
# [-0.2720813   0.17083423]
# [ 0.48993333 -0.99415568]]
```

Now that I have a projection for each item it's possible to find more useful info, such as which of the given items is closest to the query point, find its array index and derive more data from it, etc...

The problem with calling `minimize` for each item is that it becomes very slow when dealing with hundreds of thousands of items. So to try to resolve the issue I took a crack at changing the function to work with many inputs.

```
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

# This function calculate the closest projection to many hyperbolic paraboloids
def fun_array(x, p0, p1, p2, p3, p):
    u, v = x
    s = u*(p1-p0) + v*(p3-p0) + u*v*(p2-p3-p1+p0) + p0
    V = p-s
    return np.min(np.sqrt(inner1d(V,V)))

# Lets pass all the data to minimize
uv = minimize(fun_array, (0.5, 0.5), (p0, p1, p2, p3, p)).x

# Result: [ 0.25090064,  1.19732181]
# This corresponds to index 2 of my random data, 
# which is the closest projection.
```

Minimizing the function `fun_array` is much faster than the iterative approach, but it only returns the single closest projection, not all projections.

## QUESTION

Is it possible to use `minimize` to return all projections as with the iterative approach? And if not, is it at least possible to get the index of the "winning" array element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The strict answer

You have to be tricky but it's not that difficult to trick `minimize`. The point is that [`minimize` only works for scalar cost functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). But we can get away with summing up all your distances, since they are naturally nonnegative quantities and the global minimum is defined by the configuration where each distance is minimal. So instead of asking for the minimum points of `COUNT` bivariate scalar functions, instead we ask for the minimum of a single scalar function of `COUNT*2` variables. This just happens to be the sum of `COUNT` bivariate functions. But note that I'm not convinced that this will be faster, because I can imagine higher-dimensional minimum searches to be less stable than a corresponding set of lower-dimensional independent minimum searches.

What you *should* definitely do is pre-allocate memory for `uv` and insert values into that, rather than growing a list item by item a lot of times:

```
uv = np.empty((COUNT,2))
for i in range(COUNT):
    uv[i,:] = minimize(fun_single, (0.5, 0.5), (p0[i], p1[i], p2[i], p3[i], p)).x
```

Anyway, in order to use a single call to `minimize` we only need to vectorize your function, which is easier than you'd think:

```
def fun_vect(x, p0, p1, p2, p3, p):
    x = x.reshape(-1,2) # dimensions are mangled by minimize() call
    u,v = x.T[...,None] # u,v shaped (COUNT,1) for broadcasting
    s = u*(p1-p0) + v*(p3-p0) + u*v*(p2-p3-p1+p0) + p0 # shape (COUNT,3)
    return np.linalg.norm(p-s, axis=1).sum() # sum up distances for overall cost

x0 = 0.5*np.ones((COUNT,2))
uv_vect = minimize(fun_vect, x0, (p0, p1, p2, p3, p)).x.reshape(-1,2)
```

This function, as you see, extend the scalar one along columns. Each row corresponds to an independent minimization problem (consistently with your definition of the points). The vectorization is straightforward, the only nontrivial part is that we need to play around with dimensions to make sure that everything broadcasts nicely, and we should take care to reshape `x0` on input because `minimize` has a habit of flattening the array-valued input position. And of course the final result has to be reshaped again. Correspondingly, an array of shape `(COUNT,2)` has to be provided as `x0`, this is the only feature from which `minimize` can deduce the dimensionality of your problem.

Comparison for my random data:

```
>>> uv
array([[-0.13386872,  0.14324999],
       [ 2.42883931,  0.55099395],
       [ 1.03084756,  0.35847593],
       [ 1.47276203,  0.29337082]])

>>> uv_vect
array([[-0.13386898,  0.1432499 ],
       [ 2.42883952,  0.55099405],
       [ 1.03085143,  0.35847888],
       [ 1.47276244,  0.29337179]])
```

Note that I changed `COUNT` to be 4, because I like to keep every dimension distinct when testing. This way I can be sure that I run into an error if I mess up my dimensions. Also note that in general you might want to keep the complete object returned by `minimize` just to make sure that everything went fine and converged.

---

### A more useful solution

As we discussed in comments, the above solution---while perfectly answers the question---is not particularly feasible, since it takes too long to run, much longer than doing each minimization separately. The problem was interesting enough that it got me thinking. Why not try to solve the problem as exactly as possible?

What you're trying to do (now considering a single hyperboloid and a query point q) is finding the `s(u,v)` point with the [parametrization by Jaime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18861570/5067311)

```
s(u,v) = p0 + u * (p1 - p0) + v * (p3 - p0) + u * v * (p2 - p3 - p1 + p0)
```

for which the distance `d(s,q)` is minimal. Since the distance is a proper metric (in particular, it is non-negative), this is equivalent to minimizing `d(s,q)^2`. So far so good.

Let's rewrite the parametrized equation of `s` by introducing a few constant vectors in order to simplify the derivation:

```
s(u,v) = p0 + u*a + v*b + u*v*c
s - q  = p0-q0 + u*a + v*b + u*v*c
       = d + u*a + v*b + u*v*c
d(s,q)^2 = (s-q)^2
```

(In this section `^` will represent the power, because this is linear algebra.) Now, the minimum of the distance function is a stationary point, so in the `u_min,v_min` point we're looking for the gradient of `s(u,v)` with respect to `u` and `v` is zero. This is equivalent to saying that the derivative of `d(s,q)^2` with respect to both `u` and `v` has to be simultaneously zero; this gives us two nonlinear equations with the unknowns `u` and `v`:

```
2*(s-q)*ds/du = 0  (1)
2*(s-q)*ds/dv = 0  (2)
```

Expanding these two equations is a somewhat tedious job. The first equation happens to be linear in `u`, the second in `v`. I collected all the terms containing `u` in the first equation, which gave me the relationship

```
u(v) = (-v^2*b.c - v*(c.d + a.b) - a.d)/(a + v*c)^2
```

where `.` represents the dot product. The above equation tells us that for whatever `v` we choose, equation (1) will exactly be satisfied if `u` is chosen thus. So we have to solve equation (2).

What I did was expand all the terms in equation (2), and substitute `u(v)` into `u`. The original equation had polynomial terms of `1,u,v,uv,u^2,u^2v`, so I can tell you this is not pretty. With some minor assumptions of no divergence (which divergences would probably correspond to the equivalent of vertical lines in the case of a line fitting problem), we can arrive at the following beautiful equation:

```
(b.d + v*b^2)*f^2 - (c.d + a.b + 2*v*b.c)*e*f + (a.c + v*c^2)*e^2 = 0
```

with the new scalars defined as

```
e = v^2*b.c + v*(c.d + a.b) + a.d
f = (a + v*c)^2 = (a^2 + 2*v*a.c + v^2*c^2)
```

Whatever `v` solves this equation, the corresponding `(u(v),v)` point will correspond to a stationary point of the distance. We should first note that this equation considers the root of a fifth-order polynomial if `v`. There's guaranteed to be at least one real root, and in the worst case there can be as many as 5 real roots. Whether these correspond to minima, maxima, or (in unlikely cases) saddle points is open for discussion.

The real benefit of the above result is that we have a fighting chance of finding *all* the roots of the equation! This is a huge deal, since nonlinear root searching/minimization will in general give you only one root at a time, without being able to tell you if you've missed any. Enter [`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots.html). Despite all the linear algebra fluff surrounding it, we're only looking for the (at most 5!) root of a polynomial, for which we can test the distances and choose the global minimum (if necessary). If there's only one root, we can be sure that it's *the* minimum based on geometrical considerations.

Note that I haven't mentioned a caveat yet: the polynomial library can only work with one polynomial at a time. We will still have to loop over each hyperboloid manually. But here's the deal: we will be able to guarantee that we're finding the exact minimum, rather than unknowingly accepting local distance minima. And it might even be faster than `minimize`. Let's see:

```
import numpy as np

# generate dummy inputs
COUNT = 100
p0 = np.random.random_sample((COUNT,3))
p1 = np.random.random_sample((COUNT,3))
p2 = np.random.random_sample((COUNT,3))
p3 = np.random.random_sample((COUNT,3))
p = np.random.random_sample(3)


def mydot(v1,v2):
    """generalized dot product for multidimensional arrays: (...,N,3)x(...,N,3) -> (...,N,1)"""
    # (used in u_from_v for vectorized dot product)
    return np.einsum('...j,...j->...',v1,v2)[...,None]

def u_from_v(v, a, b, c, d):
    """return u(v) corresponding to zero of gradient"""
    # use mydot() instead of dot to enable array-valued v input

    res = (- v**2*mydot(b,c) - v*(mydot(c,d)+mydot(a,b)) - mydot(a,d))/np.linalg.norm(a+v*c, axis=-1, keepdims=True)**2
    return res.squeeze()

def check_distance(uv, p0, p1, p2, p3, p):
    """compute the distance from optimization results to query point"""
    u,v = uv.T[...,None]
    s = u*(p1-p0) + v*(p3-p0) + u*v*(p2-p3-p1+p0) + p0
    return np.linalg.norm(p-s, axis=-1)


def poly_for_v(a, b, c, d):
    """return polynomial representation of derivative of d(s,p)^2 for the parametrized s(u(v),v) point"""
    # only works with a scalar problem:( one polynomial at a time
    # v is scalar, a-b-c-d are 3-dimensional vectors (for a given paraboloid)

    # precompute scalar products appearing multiple times in the formula
    ab = a.dot(b)
    ac = a.dot(c)
    cc = c.dot(c)
    cd = c.dot(d)
    bc = b.dot(c)

    Poly = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial
    e = Poly([a.dot(d), cd+ab, bc])
    f = Poly([a.dot(a), 2*ac, cc])

    res = Poly([b.dot(d), b.dot(b)])*f**2 - Poly([cd+ab,2*bc])*e*f + Poly([ac,cc])*e**2
    return res


def minimize_manually(p0, p1, p2, p3, p):
    """numpy polynomial version for the minimization problem"""

    # auxiliary arrays, shape (COUNT,3)
    a = p1 - p0
    b = p3 - p0
    c = p2 - p3 - p1 + p0
    d = p0 - p

    # preallocate for collected result
    uv_min = np.empty((COUNT,2))
    for k in range(COUNT):
        # collect length-3 vectors needed for a given surface
        aa,bb,cc,dd = (x[k,:] for x in (a,b,c,d))

        # compute 5 complex roots of the derivative distance
        roots = poly_for_v(aa, bb, cc, dd).roots()
        # keep exactly real roots
        vroots = roots[roots.imag==0].real

        if vroots.size == 1:
            # we're done here
            vval, = vroots
            uval = u_from_v(vval, aa, bb, cc, dd)
            uv_min[k,:] = uval,vval
        else:
            # need to find the root with minimal distance
            uvals = u_from_v(vroots[:,None], aa, bb, cc, dd)
            uvtmp = np.stack((uvals,vroots),axis=-1)
            dists = check_distance(uvtmp, p0[k,:], p1[k,:], p2[k,:], p3[k,:], p)
            winner = np.argmin(dists) # index of (u,v) pair of minimum
            uv_min[k,:] = uvtmp[winner,:]

    return uv_min

uv_min = minimize_manually(p0, p1, p2, p3, p)
# for comparison with the minimize-based approaches:
# distances = check_distance(uv_manual,p0,p1,p2,p3,p))
```

The above example has `COUNT` of 100, but if you start with `COUNT=1` and keep running both the `minimize` version and the above exact version, you'll see roughly once in every 10-20 runs that the `minimize`-based approach misses the real minimum. So the above is safer, it's guaranteed to find the proper minima.

I also did some timing checks with `COUNT=100`, around 100 ms for the polynomial-based solution, around 200 ms for the minimize-based looping version. With `COUNT=1000`: 1 second for the polynomial, 2 seconds for the looping minimize-based. Considering how even for larger problems the above is both more precise and more efficient, I see no reason why not to use this instead.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question. Unfortunately for my use case, calling minimize once to solve the entire array slows down to a crawl with many inputs (try: 10, 100, 1k, 10k to see what happens). I'm not sure if it's due to how minimize works in the background or because of the function's nature.

Comment: @Fnord unfortunately I'm not too surprised. I've been musing a bit about your problem since yesterday, and it's possible that computing the Jacobian and especially the Hessian yourself might help with speed. If you think about it, the `COUNT*2`-dimensional problem has a Hessian which is a `COUNT*2`-by-`COUNT*2` matrix, which is actually block diagonal with `2x2` blocks. If you compute this sparse matrix by hand, it might help. And a `COUNT*2`-dimensional numerical gradient is cumbersome too. But I admit I didn't try to implement this. Does preallocation give you any significant speedup?

Comment: @Andrea Deak Preallocating does make a difference. I have another option i can use. If you look back at my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858448/speeding-up-a-closest-point-on-a-hyperbolic-paraboloid-algorithm), @Jaime gave me a different function `solve_uv` which avoids  `minimize` altogether. With a few changes I was able to vectorize his solution and from a speed perspective I'm getting very reasonable results from it. I got hopeful when I saw minimize was so much faster to find the single closest projection, but unfortunately I need the process the entire array.

Comment: @Fnord your question got me thinking. I happened to be able to solve it almost exactly, using polynomial arithmetic (albeit still looping over each hyperboloid after the other). It's twice as fast as the looping minimize-based version, but unlike that it always finds the proper minimum. Please let me know how it works for you:)

Comment: @Andrea Deak Thank you so much for putting so much thought in your answer! You are an asset to this community. Your code seems to work great but it is slower than the vectorized version I made from Jaime's non-scipy answer. Since a close approximation is good enough and faster to compute i will use that instead. [I posted my clumsy code on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164820/calculate-the-closest-point-to-many-hyperbolic-paraboloids) asking for help improving its performance. Your input would be greatly valued!

Comment: @Fnord no worries, I just like to nerd snipe myself with interesting problems;) Thanks for giving it a shot and reporting back! I might take a look at your CR post if I can find the time. Especially the fact that an esoteric method is faster than `np.dot` intrigues me (but perhaps there's less overhead since it's a ufunc). One minor note: it's Andras, not Andrea ;)